# SVN checkout via PHP

Tags: php, svn, svn-checkout

Here is how I do it:

```
svn_checkout('svn+ssh://server.com/svn_path', 'folder/');
```

But it seems the function does not recognize the svn+ssh protocol, as it gives me internal server error. With HTTP it works fine.
Is there a way to checkout?

Answer (score 1):

This example demonstrates how to check out a directory from a repository to a directory named calc:

```
svn_checkout('http://www.example.com/svnroot/calc/trunk', dirname(__FILE__) . '/calc');
```

Reference [**link**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.svn-checkout.php)

**OR**

Try this

```
// svn checkout command
$checkout = "svn --username SVN-USERNAME --password SVN-PASSWORD checkout http://SVN-REPOSITORY-LOCATION DESTINATION-FOLDER";
// run php exec command
exec($checkout);
```

Reference [**link**](http://www.brightlemon.com/blog/checkout-svn-php)

Comment: This doesn't help the OP with svn+ssh - the OP is already aware of how to use http.

Comment: Both work but with HTTP protocol, not with svn+ssh. Just tested.

Comment: can you try `$checkout = "svn co svn+ssh://server.com/svn_path folder --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username <username> --password <password> --no-auth-cache";exec($checkout);`